# Reference request for the group of units of a power series ring in one variable

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $\mathbb F_p$ denote the finite prime field of $p$ elements. What reference can be recommended for an analysis of the structure of the group of units of the power series ring $\mathbb F_p[[x]]$? There must be much known more generally when the finite field is replaced by any other field but I am most interested in the finite prime case.

Comment: I think Peter wants to know whether the units are isomorphic to a direct product of countably many copies of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ indexed by the positive integers prime to $p$ and one copy of $\mathbb{F}_p^\times$ and if so, why.

Comment: Why does this have a vote to close?

Comment: Yes I thought I had put this detail in but it got lost at some point. The expected result says $\mathbb F_p[[x]]^\times\cong\mathbb F_p^\times\times\prod_{\mathbb N}\mathbb Z_p$ and in this notation $\mathbb N$ means nothing more than `a countable infinity'. I am interested in understanding the proof - yes - but I am sure this must be a standard result in a text book which is why I badged this as reference-request.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general the multiplicative group $1+x\,A[\![x]\!]\leq U(A[\![x]\!])$ is isomorphic to the additive group of the ring $W(A)$ of big Witt vectors of $A$.  If $A$ is $p$-local for some prime $p$, then $W(A)$ is additively isomorphic to a product of copies of the ring $W_{p^\infty}(A)$ of $p$-typical Witt vectors, with one copy for each positive integer that is coprime to $p$.  If $A$ is a finite field of order $p^d$, then $W_{p^\infty}(A)$ is a complete discrete valuation ring that is additively isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p^d$ and has a natural ring isomorphism $W_{p^\infty}(A)/p\simeq A$; moreover, $W_{p^\infty}(A)$ is uniquely characterised by these properties, up to canonical isomorphism.  More concretely, $A$ can be described as $\mathbb{F}_p[t]/f(t)$ for some polynomial $f(t)$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ that divides the cyclotomic polynomial $\varphi_{p^d-1}(t)$, and there is a unique lift of $f(t)$ to $\mathbb{Z}_p[t]$ that still divides the cyclotomic polynomial, and we have $W_{p^\infty}(A)=\mathbb{Z}_p[t]/f(t)$.

For more details you can read [these notes by Lars Hesselholt](https://www.math.nagoya-u.ac.jp/%7Elarsh/papers/s03/wittsurvey.pdf), or the references listed there.

Comment: Is there a good reference? (Asking for a friend)

Comment: @DaveBenson I have added a link

Comment: Thanks especially to Neil Strickland for the very helpful details.